# Eclipse java WindowBuilder error while adding taborder on JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

The following error is occurred while using 'tab order' properties of JPanel or JFrame in Eclipse

**WindowBuilder encountered unexpected internal error.**

This could be caused by a WindowBuilder bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partialupdate, etc.

java.lang.Error: Unable to open file /resources/1.8/org/eclipse/wb/swing/FocusTraversalOnArray.java from org.eclipse.wb.swing

Comment: Check the workspace log file. It may provide some more information. Maybe try asking in the Eclipse [WindowBuilder forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/214/)